# Convert String "R.id.text1" to int id of TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, layout-inflater

MainActivity.java

```
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
        {
            String commonId="R.id.text";
            final int index=i-1;
            commonId=commonId+i;
            Log.e("MSG",index+" "+commonId);

      Integer id= getResources().getIdentifier(commonId, "id", getPackageName());

            TextView day=(TextView)daysView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            Log.e("MSG",id+" "+day +" "+commonId);
}
```

R.layout.picker

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="MON"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:text="TUE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:text="WED"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:text="THU"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_select_category"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:text="FRI"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:text="SAT"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/text7"
        android:text="SUN"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text6"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_select_category"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Log Printing

```
0 null R.id.text1 
0 null R.id.text2
```

This "picker" view is inflated in Activity.

i have tried this for "drawable" files and it works but not for getting view's ids. I have searched everywhere this is the syntax but not working here.
app package is `com.myexample.app` and activity is in `com.myexample.app.Activities` package. I don't want to write 7 click listener on textView so i want to do in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this

```
String commonId="R.id.text";
```

to this

```
String commonId="text";
```

Comment: My pleasure to help.

Answer (score 0):

try doing like this,

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
   int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("text" + i, "id", getPackageName());
   TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(resId);
}
```

Comment: What does this answer add to mine?

Comment: Don't use 'R.id.text', Just use 'text'

Comment: where you suggested?

Comment: yes, but he is also mistaken in finding view so i write whole code

Comment: Views finding are correct , now working by using 'text''